# Apache redirect of multiple PHP pages based on variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a current site that I'm keeping up though it's deprecated and all content moved to another site. Because it's been a year, I want to start redirecting people from the old site to the new, and I can do that grossly with a simple redirect.  However, I've got individual articles that I'd like to redirect to the article on the new site.

The old schema was something like:

```
https://mydomain/viewstory.php?sid=20449
```

That was imported to the new site as:

```
https://mynewdomain/works/12345
```

The data is in my MySQL database with old and new URL, and I'd like to put together a giant `.htaccess` file with all the redirects.  But currently the code I have input **does NOT** work.  That code I'm using is:

```
Redirect 301 /viewstory.php?sid=20449 https://mynewdomain/works/12345
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> Redirect 301 /viewstory.php?sid=20449 https://mynewdomain/works/12345
> ```

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive matches against the URL-path only, not the query string. To match this URL you would need to use mod_rewrite and check the `QUERY_STRING` server variable in a *condition*. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sid=20449$
RewriteRule ^viewstory\.php$ https://mynewdomain/works/12345 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `QSD` flag is necessary to discard the original query string from the redirect response.

> I'd like to put together a giant .htaccess file with all the redirects.

This may be OK if this is all you are using the old host for... redirecting to the new site *on a different server/virtualhost*. Although, how many individual redirects do you have?

However, ordinarily, if you are maintaining old and new sites on the same server/virtualhost then it is more efficient to implement 100s (or 1000s) of redirects in your application, rather than `.htaccess` (or even the server config). And only when your application has deemed the request would result in a 404. This is to ensure that normal site visitors are not impacted in any way by the redirect logic (`.htaccess` is processed on every single request).

Alternatively, you internally rewrite (in `./htaccess`) all requests of the form `/viewstory.php?sid=<something>` to a separate script and that script handles the redirects.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite all requests of the form "/viewstory.php?sid=<something>" to a PHP script
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sid=.
RewriteRule ^viewstory\.php$ manage-old-redirects.php [L]
```

In the above we *internally rewrite* (no redirect) all requests of the form `/viewstory.php?sid=<something>` to your PHP script `/manage-old-redirects.php`, in which you perform the necessary lookups to construct the redirect as required.

Comment: This is an old archive, so I've got 35,000+ items to redirect to a new domain - so it might well be the best idea to do a script redirect.  Thanks!

Comment: @walterhpdx Hhmmm, 35,000 redirects in `.htaccess` would be excessive (and a definite "no" if the same server/virtualhost is used for the new site as well). I've updated my answer with the necessary `.htaccess` directives to rewrite such requests to a PHP script that would handle the request.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite - I figured that would be too many.  I like your approach, so now I'm googling redirect PHP scripts.  Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else who is looking for this, I created a new file per @MrWhite's instructions called mod.php and in it I have:

<?php


if ( $_GET['sid'] == "1") $sid = '116';
elseif ( $_GET['sid'] == "2") $sid = '117';
elseif ( $_GET['sid'] == "3") $sid = '118';
(continued ad nauseum for all my sids)
else $sid = '35094';

header("Location: https://mynewdomain/works/$sid");
exit();

?>